# Part of a string not getting inserted

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I have a `Button` that gets the value of a `ComboBox`and inserts it into a string to send through my serial port. For some reason the value is not inserted into the string but the rest of the string is built correctly.  Can anyone tell me why?

when i `System.out.println(something);` it correctly prints the value selected in the `ComboBox` "3"

Here is my buttons `JavaFX.ActionEvent`

```
@FXML
public void setPresetButton(ActionEvent event) {
    byte _preset = (Byte) setPresetComboBox.getValue();
    try {
        something = presetNo[_preset - 1];

        byte[] command = { (byte) setPresetX,setPresetS,something,0x20};
        TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter sw = new TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter(
                twoWaySerCom.serialPort.getOutputStream());

        sw.out.write(command);
        System.out.println(something);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


byte presetNo[] = { 0X01, 0X02, 0X03, 0X04, 0X05 };
byte something;
Byte[] preset = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
byte setPresetX = 0x78;
byte setPresetS = 0x73;
```

Comment: What is the type of your combobox?

Comment: its `private ComboBox<Byte> getPresetComboBox;`

Comment: bytes `0x01`-`0x05` are suspiciously small. Are they supposed to contain the digits as (8-bit) characters or do you send control chars (SOH, STX, ETX, EOT or ENQ) on purpose?

Comment: I am just trying to send 3 characters in a string.  XS1 would be "set preset 1" for example. There is no STX,ETX checksum etc with the protocol that i am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to encode the text as ASCII and also need the characters for the digits, i.e. `'1'`, `'2'`, ..., `'5'` (encodings `0x31`, `0x32`, `0x33`,`0x34` and `0x35`) instead of the control codes for Start of Header, Start of Text, End of Text, End of Transmission and Enquiry (see [Control Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C0_.28ASCII_and_derivatives.29)).

In case you really need ASCII encoding, you can use a `String` for the encoding:

```
String s = "xs" + something + ' ';
Charset charset = StandardCharsets.US_ASCII;
byte[] command = s.getBytes(charset);
```

alternatively you can also get the correct encoding by adding `'0'` to the `byte` value:

```
byte[] command = { (byte) setPresetX, setPresetS, (byte)(something + '0'), 0x20};
```

Comment: I have just copy paste the code from another working example `byte[] command = { (byte) startTx, address, byteOne, goPreset, 0x00, something, endTx, 0x0F };` which was a typical 485- 8`byte` PelcoP string.  I am using a new "FLIR" protocol and it states raw ASCII the ascii characters i am trying to send is simply "SX1" for "set preset 1".  The `Combobox` shows an ASCII representation for ease of use for the user.

Comment: The idea is that a user can save a position to their chosen "preset" for recall later by selecting the number from a `ComboBox` and then hitting the `setpresetButton`

Comment: `"XS1".getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"))` should get you the `XS1` encoded as ASCII. BTW `0x73` and `0x78` are **lower case** `s` and `x`. I'm not familiar with the FLIR protocol though...